# Push Goals only 1 account in 2 Google Analytics codes in site

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking

*I not sure with my title, Just edit me if you have a better*

Okey, I have 2 Google Analytics codes in my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              var _gaq = _gaq || [];
              _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX-A']);
              _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
              (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
              })();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
              var _gaq = _gaq || [];
              _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX-B']);
              _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
              (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
              })();
</script>
```

And I push my **goal** like..

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Form','Submitted','Test']);
```

How to make this goal tracking for **UA-XXX-A** only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices for using multiple profiles is to name the secondary trackers -- see [Google docs for the `_gaq.push()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push). Any analytics calls in the page (like your `_trackEvent` call) that don't use a name will use the first (default) tracker.

Also, you're loading the analytics code twice. Loading it once will speed up your page and give you more reproducible data collection.

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX-A']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['t2._setAccount', 'UA-XXX-B']);
  _gaq.push(['t2._trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```